# .net core 3.1 console apps can run in a plesk hosting?

Tags: c#, telegram, .net-core-3.1

so , i've started to develop a telegram bot using `Telegram.Bot` Official Library , I Want To Know If I Develop My Bot In a `.net core 3.1` Console Application I can run it On A `HOSTING` (Not a Real VPS)???

Telegram Bots With PHP Can Be Runned In a Host , I Want To Know Is There A Way To Run Our Telegram Bot apps Written In .net core in a host (not a full vps)

There is a way to develop telegram bots in a plesk or something like that?